# Why list must be declared under the for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I know this is a beginner's question. But, I want to know why the list must be declared below the for-loop when passing it as an argument?

```
def print_list(list):

    for i in list:
        print(i)
items = ["Bag", "Cellphone", "Laptop"]

print_list(items)
```

Comment: It only needs to be declared ***above*** the function call (or anything else referencing it). Where did you get the idea that it needs to be below the loop?

Comment: I am unsure about the question you are asking. Can you post the alternative you tried (where you did not place the list declaration "above the for loop")? Perhaps then we can explain why that alternative cannot work.

Comment: It just crossed my mind while studying Python and doing the exercises stated in the challenge. That's why I wonder if it needs to be declared only below the for-loop or not.

Answer (score 0):

`print_list` is a function so you can declare a list below that function or above it doesn't matter. then you pass that list as a parameter so it doesn't make sense where the list will be declared below or above the function.